# ggplot2 geom_text position text on horizontal grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Hi I am struglling with getting labels in a grouped horizontal barplot in the right position. I know that there have been similar questions before but I dont seem to ge the answers to work.

My data ("Correlation") looks like this:

```
Trait r      se      Disease   significant
1     0.4    0.06    A         *
1     0.1    0.06    B
1     -0.05  0.03    C
2     0.4    0.06    A         *
2     0.1    0.05    B
2     -0.06  0.03    C         *
3     0.04   0.06    A         *
3     0.2    0.05    B         *
3     0.3    0.04    C         *
```

And my code:

```
grouped_plot <- ggplot(data=Correlation, aes(x=Trait, y=r, 
fill=Disease)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", 
width=0.9)+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = r - se, ymax = r + se), 
width = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9), stat="identity", 
color=rgb(100,100,100, maxColorValue = 255)) + coord_flip() +
theme_minimal() +       
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-0.8,0.8,by=0.1)) +  
theme(legend.position="none")  + ggtitle("XXX") + theme(plot.title = 
element_text(size=11) )

grouped_plot + geom_text(aes(x=Trait, y=r + 0.07 * sign(r),      
label=format(significant), hjust=ifelse(r>0,0,1)), 
position=position_dodge(0.9), size=5, color=rgb(100,100,100, 
maxColorValue = 255) )
```

But howevery I adjust the parameters, the stars are never quite centered vertically + the distance to the errorbars is different each time :

[image]

Adding "se" to the y-parameter in geom_text also doesnt make the stars to be in the same distance to the error-bars ( for the error-bars that go in the negative direction )

```
grouped_plot + geom_text(aes(x=Trait, y=r +se + 0.01 * sign(r),      
label=format(significant), hjust=ifelse(r>0,0,1)), 
position=position_dodge(0.9), size=5, color=rgb(100,100,100, maxColorValue  
= 255) )
```

[image]

Does anybody have a solution? I would be very greatful

Comment: One thing that I'm seeing while messing around with this is that it seems to be partly typographical. The asterisk is slightly superscript; change the `label` argument to something like `"o"` or `"I"` to see that. I'm thinking there might be a unicode you can use instead for a star shape that is centered

Comment: I does make a difference- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in a comment above, I think there's a typographical issue: the asterisk character is set in a slight superscript, so it hovers above the center line you'd expect it to be on. Rather than using that specific character, I tried using a `geom_point` to get a little more control than the `geom_text`, then mapped the significance variable to shape. I changed the data slightly, to make a column `is_sig` that would have values for every observation, because I was having trouble getting things lined up when there were `NA` values (makes the dodging difficult).

The other trick I used was for positioning just outside the errorbars, taking sign into account. I set a variable `gap` to keep a uniform offset for each star, then in the `geom_point`, calculate the y position as `r` plus or minus the standard error + gap.

Mess around with the shape used; this was the closest to your asterisk I could get quickly, but there might be a unicode character that you can put in instead. On my Mac, I can easily get a star character, but you need an extra step to get that unicode character to show in the plot. Check out the [shape reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#point) also.

In the `geom_point`, set `show.legend = F` to keep the points from showing up in the legend. Or omit this, and create a shape legend to show what the asterisk means. Note the warning that those `NA` shapes are being removed.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

# ... reading data

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(is_sig = ifelse(is.na(significant), "not significant", "significant"))

gap <- 0.01

ggplot(df2, aes(x = as.factor(Trait), y = r, fill = Disease, group = Disease)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.9) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = r - se, ymax = r + se), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = is_sig, y = r + sign(r) * (se + gap)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
             size = 2, show.legend = F) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("significant" = 8, "not significant" = NA))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with the star shape and then providing this perfect solution!

Answer (score 4):

play around with one value of `hjust` and some `angle` outside aes

```
 ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Trait, y=r, fill=Disease)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), show.legend = F)+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = r - se, ymax = r + se), 
                width = 0.3, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-0.8,0.8,by=0.1)) +  
  theme_minimal() +       
  geom_text(aes(x=Trait, y=r + se + 0.01 * sign(r),      
            label=format(significant)), position=position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            angle =270, hjust=.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you a lot - doing it outside of aes does the trick.

It still does not solve the problem that the stars have different distances to the errorbars when those are of different lengths. Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: See my edits. You forgot to include `se` in the `y` call.

Comment: Thank you! It works indeed for this plot but I have some more data where I also want to include a star on bars that go into the negative direction (accidentlyy chose an example here where that is not the case) and then of course it does not work with adding "se" as the star will move more towards 0 again.

Comment: Is this not fixed by the sign(r)? Otherwise you can try `ifelse` to change the orientation or the multiplication factor. Include also a reproducible example in your question. Then we will have a look